# “browsing” metaphors

Tags: веб-программирование

Строки из книги по андроид:

> WebView can also assist you with common “browsing” metaphors, such as
>   history list of visited URLs to support backwards and forwards
>   navigation.

Что это за *“browsing” metaphors* и как это словосочетание вообще переводится на русский?